# How to generate the following string?

Tags: node.js, json, jq

Consider the following a snippet from my **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.camelcase": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/lodash.kebabcase": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/lodash.lowercase": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/lodash.upperfirst": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/mime": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.1",
    "async": "^3.2.2",
    "aws-arn": "^1.0.1",
}
```

From this, I want to generate the following string -

```
@types/lodash.camelcase@^4.3.6 @types/lodash.kebabcase@^4.1.6 @types/lodash.lowercase@^4.3.6 @types/lodash.upperfirst@^4.3.6 @types/mime@^2.0.3 @types/swagger-jsdoc@^6.0.1 async@^3.2.2 aws-arn@^1.0.1
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming actually valid JSON, you can use [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-(foo)) and [`join`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)):

```
.dependencies | to_entries | map("\(.key)@\(.value)") | join(" ")
```

String interpolation gives you a little more flexibility compared to using join twice. YMMV, and for sample cases join will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

As `jq` is tagged: Make a valid JSON, then disassemble with `to_entries`, and `join` twice:

```bash
jq -r '.dependencies | to_entries | map(join("@")) | join(" ")' package.json
```

```
@types/lodash.camelcase@^4.3.6 @types/lodash.kebabcase@^4.1.6 @types/lodash.lowercase@^4.3.6 @types/lodash.upperfirst@^4.3.6 @types/mime@^2.0.3 @types/swagger-jsdoc@^6.0.1 async@^3.2.2 aws-arn@^1.0.1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/j7nkDar3PrF)